# After one call to myfun, new parametrization does not affect the result, which conforms to the first call

Tags: octave

I am new to Octave although I can say I am an expert Matlab user. I am running Octave on a Linux server (Red Hat) remotely through PuTTY, from a windows machine.

I am observing a very strange behavior in Octave. I call myfun(a) which performs as expected giving the sought results. Now, if I run, say, myfun(b) with b!=a, I get again myfun(a). Clear -f does not solve the problem. I need to reboot octave to change the parameters.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot
Francesco

This is the code for the function I mentioned:

```
function [a, v, obj, infos, iter] = mle_garch( p )

    #{
    % this function estimates the GARCH(1,1)  parameters
    % it is assumed we pass the adjusted price level p
    #}
    global y = (diff(log(p))-mean(diff(log(p))))*100;
    global h = zeros(size(y));
    a0 = [var(y)*0.9; 0.8; 0.1];
    [a, obj, infos, iter] = sqp(a0, @loglike_garch, [], @loglike_con, [], [], 1000);
    v = sqrt(h * 260);

endfunction

function g = loglike_garch( a )

    global y h
    n = length(y);
    h(1) = var(y);
    for i = 2 : n,
        h(i) = a(1) + a(2) * h(i-1) + a(3) * y(i-1)^2;
    endfor
    g = 0.5 * ( sum(log(h)) + sum(y.^2./h) ) / n;

endfunction

function f = loglike_con( a )

    f = [1;0;0;0] + [0 -1 -1;eye(3)] * a;

endfunction
```

Comment: you'll have to show us the code of `myfun`. We don't know what it's supposed to be doing. Of course, it is possible for a function to return the same result for different inputs, but we'll need to see the function. Also, what Octave version are you using?

Comment: well, I am also new to this forum, therefore, apologies for the horrible code formatting. This code is a likelihood estimation of a garch(1,1). It returns the yearly volatility in percentages. But I guess I understand now what is the problem. The global variables I have defined are instantiated in wrongly, I should have said:
global y h
 y = (diff(log(p))-mean(diff(log(p))))*100;
 h = zeros(size(y));
This problem is related to the fact that I cannot used nested functions in octave. However, I have a further question.

Comment: Where are those global var actually shown and how can I clear them from the code? I do not seem to remember they were shown by the "whos" function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the `myfun` you mentioned is `mle_garch`. The problem is the way you're initializing the global `h` and `v` variables (do you really need them to be global?). When you have a piece of code like this

```
global y = (diff(log(p))-mean(diff(log(p))))*100;
global h = zeros(size(y));
```

the values of `y` and `h` are  defined the first time only. You can change their values later on, but this specific lines will never be ran again. Since your code only uses the input argument to define these two variables, the value which you use to run the function the first time will be used every single other time. If you really want to keep those variables global, replace it with the following:

```
global y;
global h;
y = (diff(log(p))-mean(diff(log(p))))*100;
h = zeros(size(y));
```

But I don't see any reason to keep them global so just don't make them global.

Also, you mentioned this code worked fine in Matlab. I was under the impression that you couldn't initialize global and persistent variables in Matlab which would make your code illegal in Matlab.

Comment: It worked in Matlab but with nested functions. I need them to be global because this is the only way to call a paramtric function without passing part of the parameters (which are defined somewhere else). I am ading a clear -g at the end just to be sure...... F

Comment: @user2747955 if it's the correct answer, mark it as such on the check button on the top left side of the answer.